# Dynamic Cell Conditional Formatting by Row

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

The following conditional formatting in Excel needs to be done in VBA code such that the row number is the same (ie. A1/Y1, A2/Y2) and cells are considered together when formatting Column Y as you move through the data set.

Rule: Formula AND($A1="1003b", $F1="NULL")

Format: Pink Fill

Applies to =$F:$F

This did not work.

```
Set MyRangeF = Range("$F:$F")
       With MyRangeF
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="AND($A1=""1000b"",$F1=""NULL"")"
                .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
                .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 153) 'pink
       End With
```

I've yet to find an example that shows how to do this dynamically in a way that I can understand it. VB newbie here.

Comment: I believe that `Formula1:="AND($A1=""1000b"",$F1=""NULL"")"` should be `Formula1:="=AND($A1=""1000b"",$F1=""NULL"")"`

Comment: and you say column Y but your code does column F, maybe you need to replace all the `F`s with `Y`s

Comment: It should be F yes. That was an oversight. That updated formula (thank you!) only applies to F1 (not the rest of the field). I need it to apply to the entire column.

Comment: `Formula1:="=AND(A1=""1000b"",F1=""NULL"")"` works OK for me: any row with "1000b" in A and "NULL" in F highlights the cell in col F on that row.

Comment: ...but make sure there are no pre-existing rules on that range or your code may be working on the wrong rule when you call (eg) `FormatConditions(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Safer to do it like this:

```vb
Set MyRangeF = Range("$F:$F")
With MyRangeF.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                                  Formula1:="=AND($A1=""1000b"",$F1=""NULL"")")
    .StopIfTrue = False
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 153) 'pink
End With
```

...or you might update the wrong CF rule in the case where the range already had one or more rules applied.

Comment: This only applies the formatting to cell F1 . I need it to hit every cell in the column but interpret what's in the corresponding A column at the same time.

Comment: When you use a formula for CF, it adjusts automatically.  Did you try it out?

Comment: ...if you look at the CF rule for F2, etc, you should be able to see that.

Comment: I got it to work correctly this morning. Thank you so much!!